# Open image link in default gallery of the device

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-gallery

Is it possible I want to open on ImageButton click that image should get open on default Gallery of particular device. This is not for android or ios app. This I want to do for my web application on which user see one single image on screen & once clicked then it should get open in their default Gallery application.

Comment: Write your effort applied code either any fiddle so we can review your effort and answer accordigly

Comment: @Kabali I don't even know this things is possible or not for web applications